# Isomorphism between quotients of linear groups

Tags: group-theory, projective-geometry

Suppose that $n$ is even. Is it true that

$$\mathrm{SL}_n (\mathbb{R})/\{ \pm I \} \times \{\pm 1\} \cong \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})/{\sim}$$

where $A\sim B$ if and only if $A=aB$ for some $a\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$? I am asking about an isomorphism as multiplicative groups. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Isomorphism in what category? The LH group is disconnected, the RH group is connected.

Comment: @AndreaMori Just as multiplicative groups.

Comment: @AndreaMori How is $PGL(n,\mathbb{R})$ connected for even $n$? Sign of the $\det$ makes sense even after projectivising for even $n$.

Comment: You might try and prove that the RH group ${\rm PGL}_n({\mathbb R})$ has trivial centre.